# in my plugin i want to change the function the_content

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to change the_content which resides in /wp-includes/post-template.php from

```
function the_content($more_link_text = null, $stripteaser = false) {
    $content = get_the_content($more_link_text, $stripteaser);
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
    $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
    echo $content;
}
```

into

```
function the_content($more_link_text = null, $stripteaser = false) {
    $content = get_the_content($more_link_text, $stripteaser);
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
    echo $content;
}
```

how do I accomplish this in my plugin **without touching the wordpress code** (leaving my code upgrade compatible)? I know that certain functions can be replaced, but this one?

Comment: I'm curious, is that str_replace a problem for you?  I'm trying to remember what its for...

Comment: yes it is. I am injecting a google tracking tag in wp_head and it contains a CDATA closing tag which gets replaced by th str_replace function.

Comment: CDATA and `wp_head` details should be in the Question. The `<head>`  has nothing to do with `the_content`, does it?

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has a list of core functions that can be over-ridden in themes and plugins; they're called pluggable functions:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions

`the_content()` isn't in that list, so it's not directly replaceable.

If you don't want to edit the WordPress code, there's no easy way to do it. The only option would be to create a local copy of the function (called `myTheme_the_content()`, or something similar), and make sure that you change references in your theme to call that instead.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in WordPress code itself: `$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);`. See [Actions and filters are NOT the same thing…](http://ottopress.com/2011/actions-and-filters-are-not-the-same-thing/).

You can hook into that filter and modify the content:

```
<?php
/* Plugin Name: Modify Content */

add_filter( 'the_content', 'mod_content_so_17749899' );
function mod_content_so_17749899( $content )
{
    // http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags
    if( is_admin() ) // Prevent this hook in admin area
        return $content;

    // Manipulate $content
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work because the str_replace filter in the main function is applied **after** your suggested filter. This is why I need to replace the function.

Comment: @AleV, sure shot. I had the feeling I was overlooking something.

Comment: Also I found out that this added_filter is not being considered at all in my wp_head or woocommerce_thankyou functions (but in footer.php for instance). confused...